# Neo4j Cypher query empty collect makes the entire result empty

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have been facing wierd problem, I have tried to get data from the neo4j graph that I have built.Here is my query

```
MATCH (u1:User {user_id: 4})-[:FOLLOWS]->(u2:User)-[]->(r1:Rest{city_id: 1})
WITH COLLECT ({ REST: r1.res_id}) as rows
MATCH (u1:User {user_id: 4})-[rel]->(r2:Rest{city_id: 1})
WHERE NOT (u1:User {user_id: 4})-[rel : BEEN_THERE | ADD_REVIEW]->(r2:Rest{city_id: 1})
WITH rows + COLLECT ({ REST: r2.res_id}) AS allrows
UNWIND allrows as row 
RETURN row.REST as RESTAURANT_ID, count(row.REST) as COUNT
ORDER BY COUNT desc
LIMIT 15;
```

However when the result of COLLECT ({ REST: r2.res_id}) are empty the entire result becomes empty. Also the query is unable to identify rows from 1st match and return undefined `rows`. Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pattern doesn't match any path, the result will be empty indeed.

You have to split the `MATCH` in 2 and make the second one `OPTIONAL`, or in your actual case, stop matching the same `u1` node over and over again:

```
MATCH (u1:User {user_id: 4})
OPTIONAL MATCH (u1)-[:FOLLOWS]->(:User)-->(r1:Rest {city_id: 1})
WITH u1, collect({ REST: r1.res_id }) AS rows
OPTIONAL MATCH (u1)-->(r2:Rest {city_id: 1})
WHERE NOT (u1)-[:BEEN_THERE | ADD_REVIEW]->(r2)
WITH rows + collect({ REST: r2.res_id }) AS allrows
UNWIND allrows as row 
RETURN row.REST AS RESTAURANT_ID, count(row.REST) AS COUNT
ORDER BY COUNT desc
LIMIT 15
```

I'm not sure about the first `OPTIONAL MATCH` in your case (you only mention the second `collect` as being a blocker), but if you want the aggregation of both patterns where each can be empty, here you go.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank for your answer! It's working correctly.

Comment: @AditKaushal Don't hesitate to [accept (and vote for)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer then.